# Remove margin between carousel images

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, carousel, carousel-slider

Why is there a vertical margin line between images in this Flutter carousel?
The line is flickering when I slide the carousel.

> This bug happens on the device (Nokia 7 Plus) but not the emulator.

```dart
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Text('Test'),
            CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
                aspectRatio: 1.8,
              ),
              items: List.generate(5, ((i) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.grey[200],
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Image.network(
                        'http://picsum.photos/id/$i/400/200',
                      ),
                      Text('TEST'),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              })),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue I've got from container border. So if you use container on top widget it will have padding and will get this. It is easier to deal with Stack widget in this case.

```dart
CarouselSlider(
  options: CarouselOptions(
    aspectRatio: 1.8,
    viewportFraction: .4,
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  ),
  items: List.generate(5, ((i) {
    return itemBUild(i);
  })),
),
```

And item build

```dart
Widget itemBUild(int id) {
  return Stack(
    fit: StackFit.expand,
    children: [
      // Image.network(
      //   'http://picsum.photos/id/$i/400/200',
      // ),
      Positioned.fill(
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red, border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Text('TEST', textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't.

Comment: Are you referring  to the gap between images?

Comment: Yes, the gap should be removed.

Comment: Does not work any better. Same bug except I have a red gap instead of a white gap.

Comment: Seems like too device specific now

Comment: Can you try with `padEnds: false,`

Comment: padEnds does not work, sorry.